# Can't find XML in httprequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, soap, soapui

I have an existing asp page which largely can't/won't change which calls a service, sending an XML document.

```vb
Private Function QueryXYZ(ByVal strStreet1 As String, _
                        ByVal strStreet2 As String, _
                        ByVal strCity As String, _
                        ByVal strState As String, _
                        ByVal strZipMain As String, _
                        ByRef objDomDoc As DOMDocument, _
                        ByRef blnStreetMatch) As Boolean

On Error GoTo errorHandler

Dim intCount As Integer
Dim lngErrNum As Long
Dim objResult As IXMLDOMNode
Dim objResultSet As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim objXMLHTTP As New ServerXMLHTTP
Dim strErrDesc As String
Dim strFault As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strResults As String
Dim strSoap As String

'CO 11784 - start
'Build Soap XML request
strSoap = _
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/'>" & _
    "<soap:Body>" & _
        "<MatchAddress xmlns='http://(address/'>" & _
                    "<MatchParms>" & _
                        "<Firm />" & _
                        "<Street1>" & strStreet1 & "</Street1>" & _
                    "</MatchParms>" & _
        "</MatchAddress>" & _
    "</soap:Body>" & _
"</soap:Envelope>"
'CO 11784 - end
'Load Request into XML document
objDomDoc.async = False
objDomDoc.loadXML (strSoap)

'Check for syntax errors in Request
If objDomDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise 10620, "Query", "Error parsing generated xml query: [" & objDomDoc.parseError.reason & _
        "]" & "[" & objDomDoc.parseError.srcText & "]"
End If

'Send the Request
objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", mstrGISURL, False
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "soapaction", "http://sampleaddress.com/MatchAddress"
objXMLHTTP.send objDomDoc

'Load Response
strResults = Replace(objXMLHTTP.responseText, "&quot;", """")
strResults = Replace(strResults, "&gt;", ">")
strResults = Replace(strResults, "&lt;", "<")
strResults = Replace(strResults, "&apos;", "'")
objDomDoc.loadXML (strResults)
```

I want to set it to talk to a new (non-WCF) service I'm writing.

```c#
public XmlDocument Matchaddress(string AddressInXML)
```

(I know that parameter call is almost certainly wrong, it's set that way just to test it using the service.asmx form)

The problem is, I can't find where the XML is located in the request. I've checked the and the input stream with a test function:

```c#
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
    string requestContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();


    StreamWriter Sw = System.IO.File.CreateText( @"C:\Temp\testfile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        Sw.WriteLine (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys[i] + Environment.NewLine);
        //if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys[i] == "SOAPAction")
        //{
        string soaphd = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys[i];
        string soapTXT = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[soaphd];
        Sw.WriteLine(soapTXT + Environment.NewLine);
        //}
    }
    Sw.Close();
```

And can't find it.

I am clearly doing something wrong.  I'm not sure if there's a change that needs making to that classic ASP code, no matter how hard it will be to do. I can't tell if I need to find the location and then change the input parameter (or remove it entirely) or if I need to know what the right parameter is first, and then the data will magically appear.

I don't know that much about that "soapaction" header - does it need to match the address of the new service, or can it be some generic (or just plain incorrect) other address?  Same question for the

```xml
<MatchAddress xmlns='http://(address/'>"
```

line in the XML - could that be bollixing it up by not being a matching address?

I don't even see the XML when I try to run it in SOAPUI, so whether that means anything or not I dunno.

More details can be provided as requested.

Comment: This is not Classic ASP. How come people vote questions like this up when it's clearly tagged wrong??

Comment: The page from which I'm receiving the call is in classic ASP, I am writing a service in C#.

Let me know what the right tags are, and I'll update them accordingly.

Maybe then you'll be able to help?

Comment: Ok, but none of the code is Classic ASP and once a request is sent it's just like any other vanilla HTTP request so it's not relevant to the question and just bloats the Classic ASP question queue some more.

Comment: Tell me the right tags, and if necessary the correct title of the question, and I'll happily update it so it will no longer clog the wrong queue.

Comment: I have removed the Classic ASP tag the others seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was close using the stream reader, I was just reading it into the wrong kind of object.  This gives me access to the entire XML :

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
using (Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
     {
         // Move to begining of input stream and read
         receiveStream.Position = 0;
         using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
         {
             // Load into XML document
             xdoc.Load(readStream);
         }
     }
```

Dumping the resulting XML into a string allowed me to get at anything I wanted, any way I care to.  No need to worry about the parameters in the function definition at all.